How to extract session in next.js
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body >
        <SessionProvider >
        <Toaster/>
        <RegisterModal/>
        <LoginModal/>
        <Layouts>
        {children}
        </Layouts>
        </SessionProvider>
        </body>
    </html>

Help me to extract sessions so that I can pass it to the <SessionProvider> , I don't know how to extract the session object. I can have only children.

What session? Please include a [mre].

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

make a function;
"use server";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
export async function getSession() {
  const session = cookies().get("session")?.value;
  if (!session) return null;
  
  return session;
}

use
//import getSession()
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const session = await getSession();
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body >
        <SessionProvider >
        <Toaster/>
        <RegisterModal/>
        <LoginModal/>
        <Layouts>
        {children}
        </Layouts>
        </SessionProvider>
        </body>
    </html>


Thanks for answer, but this is not the exact  problem that  i am facing right now . The exact problem is unable to wrap  in the layout.tsx file,i can't archive this by creating a different client component if you have any solution then give it to me

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78968909/9303782

@MrutunjayPradhan pls refer us a minimal repo of your project because we don't know how and from where the sessionProvider are importing and what's it code.

layout
//import getSession()
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const session = await getSession();
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body >
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
        <Toaster/>
        <RegisterModal/>
        <LoginModal/>
        <Layouts>
        {children}
        </Layouts>
        </SessionProvider>
        </body>
    </html>

context
// SessionContext.tsx
"use client";
import React, { createContext, useContext, ReactNode, useState } from "react";

interface SessionContextType {
  session: any;
}

const SessionContext = createContext<SessionContextType | undefined>(undefined);

interface SessionProviderProps {
  session: any;
  children: ReactNode;
}

const SessionProvider: React.FC<SessionProviderProps> = ({ session, children }: SessionProviderProps) => {
  
  return (
    <SessionContext.Provider value={{ session }}>
      {children}
    </SessionContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useSession = (): SessionContextType => {
  const context = useContext(SessionContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useSession must be used within a SessionProvider");
  }
  return context;
};

export default SessionProvider;

use in client component
const {session} = useSession() 

